# trigger that monitors the value of an specific field

Tags: sql, database, triggers

I hope someone can help me with the following: I
need to know if it is possible to implement a trigger that monitors
the value of an specific field, and when it changes the value, it should update the value of another field in another table.

Comment: Could you say what programming language or platform you're using?

Comment: I am trying to implement the same in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the below example

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.objects
      WHERE name = 'reminder' AND type = 'TR')
   DROP TRIGGER Person.reminder;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER reminder
ON Person.Address
AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
IF ( UPDATE (StateProvinceID) OR UPDATE (PostalCode) )
BEGIN
RAISERROR (50009, 16, 10)
END;
GO
-- Test the trigger.
UPDATE Person.Address
SET PostalCode = 99999
WHERE PostalCode = '12345';
GO
```